# How bitmap is stored using byte array

Tags: c++, image, arrays

My friend was asked that given a monochrome image, how it's saved in byte array  before he's asked to mirror the image along its center y axis during an interview. The function signature is given below:

```
void mirrorImage(byte image[], int width, int height){


}
```

So as you can see the width and height of the image are already given in the signature. I think I can manipulate the image by reading it line by line, keeping a counter, whenever my counter equals the width, I know it's time to read the next row. Is this how image is stored with byte array? I don't really have any experience with image processing or byte array. Thanks!

EDIT:
Each bit in the byte represents a pixel.

Comment: Which byte array? Who programmed it? Which library? It _completely_ depends....?!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's monochrome, I'm making the assumption that each bit in the byte represents a pixel.

Your approach is sound.  Just be sure to reverse the bits in each byte, as well as reversing the bytes in the row.

Also, if the width is not a multiple of 8, you'll have to shift all the bytes to the left by the remainder (`width mod 8`), and carry overflow bits from left to right across the row.